# How to add new partition to RAID-1 array on Redhat FC10?

Tags: partitioning, fedora, raid-1, mdadm

I have a RH FC10 system with RAID 1 partitions, here is mdadm.conf:

```
# mdadm.conf written out by anaconda
DEVICE partitions
MAILADDR root

ARRAY /dev/md1 level=raid1 num-devices=2 metadata=0.90 UUID=9588bfe1:ddfd5858:1067c814:ac499922
ARRAY /dev/md3 level=raid1 num-devices=2 metadata=0.90 UUID=3895ca46:c1526588:d48acd7e:c153aa83
ARRAY /dev/md4 level=raid1 num-devices=2 metadata=0.90 UUID=ebd4920f:b46c1f18:2eced24a:a21ca861
ARRAY /dev/md2 level=raid1 num-devices=2 metadata=0.90 UUID=048e8198:5d6d9682:d3a1e5c3:d475ad80
ARRAY /dev/md0 level=raid1 num-devices=2 metadata=0.90 UUID=d89ec2de:079d4be5:e00ee8f5:fcb19188
```

I want to carve off 500MB from md4 to make a new partition (for an AFS cache).  I haven't touched mdadm or any other disk partitioning tools in years.  md4 is 50GB and less than 10% used.  What's the easiest way of doing this?